# I'm creating a function to search for " unique" words in a file

Tags: python

I'm creating a function to search for **unique** words in a file. These words have an even number of characters and appear more than once in the text. Right now, I am having trouble with an error:

> NameError: name 'strip' is not defined

Here is my code:

```
    def evenWords(inFile,outFile):
    with open(inFile, 'r') as inF:
        count = 0
        lst = []
        outF = open(outFile, 'w')
            for line in inF:
                line = line.split(" ")
                for word in line:
                    word = word.strip(strip.punctuation)
                    word = word.lower()
                    wordCount = 0
                if (len(word)%2) == 0:
                    lst.append(word)
                if word in lst:
                    wordCount +=1
                if wordCount > 1:
                    outF.write(word + "\n")
                    count +=1
        return count

    inF.close()
    outF.close()
```

I would like to know why this is happening. I have tried importing string.

Comment: it should be string.punctuation not strip.punctuation

Comment: Also, you'd rather unindent `wordCount = 0` one level; it does not need to be executed in `for word in line` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want string.punctuation, and not 'strip.punctuation'.  Use this code:

```
def evenWords(inFile,outFile):
with open(inFile, 'r') as inF:
    count = 0
    lst = []
    outF = open(outFile, 'w')
        for line in inF:
            line = line.split(" ")
            for word in line:
                word = word.strip(string.punctuation)
                word = word.lower()
                wordCount = 0
            if (len(word)%2) == 0:
                lst.append(word)
            if word in lst:
                wordCount +=1
            if wordCount > 1:
                outF.write(word + "\n")
                count +=1
    return count

inF.close()
outF.close()
```

Comment: I've been staring at this code for more than an hour and didn't notice...thank you for that. That explains why the import string didn't seem relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: not really an answer.

I'll rewrite your code in a different style, just to get you interested. You might notice that it reads easier. Also, it would be much easier to reason about and test. Sorry, had to use some [slightly advanced concepts](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

```
import string


def normalize(s):
  return s.strip(string.punctuation).strip(string.whitespace).lower()


def isAcceptable(s):
  return len(s) % 2 == 0


def makeWords(stream):
  for line in stream:
    words = line.split(' ')
    for word in words:
      if isAcceptable(word):
        yield normalize(word)


def findDuplicates(words):
  # sets are much faster for member searching.
  seen_words = set()
  # we only want to report a word once.
  reported_words = set()
  for word in words:
    if word in seen_words and word not in reported_words:
      yield word
      reported_words.add(word)
    seen_words.add(word)


def main():
  with open('words.txt') as input_file:
    for word in findDuplicates(makeWords(input_file)):
      print word
  # here input_file closes automatically
```

BTW it will only report a duplicate once, while your code reports a duplicate word every time it's found: if you find a word repeated 100 times, your code reports it 99 times.